# How to show or hide Primefaces chart Legend independently when you have two charts in the same view?

Tags: javascript, jsf, charts, primefaces, jqplot

I have 2 charts in the same page. I'd like to show legends just in one chart, not both, but I have just a global solution. Thats my javascript code:

```
$.jqplot.preDrawHooks.push(function () {
this.legend.show = true;});
```

and my xhtml:

```
<p:chart id="chart17" responsive="true" type="bar"  model="#{chart17Bean.barModel}"  />
<p:chart id="chart18" responsive="true" type="bar"  model="#{chart18Bean.barModel}" />
```

Edited: I'm using Primefaces 6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this JS function on page

```
function removeLegend() 
{
     this.cfg.legend = {
          show: false
     };
}
```

and then in your managed bean add

```
barModel.setExtender("removeLegend");
```

where *barModel* is model of chart you want to have legend hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces 8, Chart Js, you could set legend display to false

```
Legend legend = new Legend();
legend.setDisplay(false);
options.setLegend(legend);
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved my issue

```
yourChart.options = {
          legend: {
            display: false,
           }
      };
```

Comment: and where does 'yourChart' come from? This won't work in PrimeFaces